# how to get random string value from list - android

Tags: android, string, random, youtube-api

I have a few youtube API keys for my android project.
eg :

```
YOUTUBE_API_KEY1 = XXXXXXXXXXX
     YOUTUBE_API_KEY2 = BBBBBBBBBBB
     YOUTUBE_API_KEY3 = NNNNNNNNNNN
```

and I want that my String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = random key from the keys list.

how can I do it?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use Random Class to get Random value

```
Java.util.Random
```

Get Random index value from list and use it.

```
index = new Random().nextInt(list.size())
item = list.get(index)
```